# Jackson MismatchedInputException (no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

I am using `SpringBoot 2.3.1-RELEASE` and am trying to deserialize JSON string to a POJO containing list of objects but I keep running into this error:

Cannot construct instance of `com.response.dto.RootDTO` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('Meta')
at [Source: (String)""Meta":[{"DimensionName":"Version","DimensionId":"3b4860b9-b215-4192-bd7a-a76f377fc465","DimensionType":"Regular","Alias":"C0","AttributeId":"211d5-d91f-40ec-9668-20e0da2ae7b3","AttributeName":"Version Name","AttributeKey":"VersionKey"; line: 1, column: 1]

This is what my JSON string looks like (but with escape chars in eclipse):

{"Meta":[{"DimensionName":"Version", "DimensionId":"3b4860b9-b215-4192-bd7a-a76f377fc465, "DimensionType":"Regular","Alias":"C0","AttributeId":"211b33d5-d91f-40ec-9668-20e0da2ae7b3","AttributeName":"Version Name","AttributeKey":"VersionKey"}]}.

Here is the class I want to deserialize it to:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
public class RootDTO 
{
  @JsonProperty("Meta")
  private List<MetaDTO> Meta;
}


 @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
 @Data
 public class MetaDTO 
{

 @JsonProperty("DimensionName")
 private String DimensionName;

 @JsonProperty("AttributeId")
 private String AttributeId;

 @JsonProperty("AttributeName")
 private String AttributeName;

 @JsonProperty("Name")
 private String Name;

 @JsonProperty("Alias")
 private String Alias;
}
```

This is the code that blows up when trying to read the value:

```
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
        
  objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
         
        objectMapper.readValue(jsonFormattedString, RootDTO.class));
```

I only see this issue while running `Junit` (version : 4.12). I see `jackson-databind-2.11.0`, `spring-test-5.2.7.RELEASE` in the stack trace. However, I debug using a call from browser or postman it works fine. I am not sure why it is looking for the string Meta when I have specified it to be a list. What could be causing this issue? Any suggestions?

Edit: Turns out that the string which was being supplied to the `ObjectMapper` isn't the correct one. There is this line of code
 `String jsonFormattedString = responseEntity.getBody().substring(1,        responseEntity.getBody().lastIndexOf("\"")).replaceAll("\\\\", "");` which makes my mocked string invalid. I'll need to figure out why we are doing this though.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first letter's of variable to lowwer case. And remove the JsonProperty.

As below. And auto generate the setter and getter.

private String DimensionName;

```
 private String attributeId;
 private String attributeName;
 private String name;

 public void setName(String name){
       this.name=name;
 }
 .........
 .........
 //All setter getter
```

Add `@JsonGetter("Meta")` each getter method.

For example as below.

```
@JsonGetter("Meta")
public List<Meta> getMeta(){

return meta;

}
```

Comment: Thanks but I think I've found my issue. Please see the edit above.

Comment: If you post the JSON to String it will do tab with forward Slash.

Comment: You can directly add Json string no need that replaces.

Comment: String bjsonString = json;

Comment: Issue due to your setter getter method with all capital letters

Comment: If I don't do this in my source code -`String jsonFormattedString = responseEntity.getBody().substring(1,        responseEntity.getBody().lastIndexOf("\"")).replaceAll("\\\\", "");` then it blows up with the exact same error when reading the value of the JSON string which makes me think that the actual responseBody content is different from what is getting printed on the console.